# Capturing video of desktop using any media player

Tags: windows-7-x64

I want to record how to execute a java program using eclipse.
Can you please tell me how to record desktop video using any media player?

I have tried open capture device but i am stuck.
Where do the videos i record get stored.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to record your whole session(audio & video) on the desktop and also the program you are executing.
Try faststone capture(evaluation copy).I hope it helps.